# SQL Server : exclude rows with specific values

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I need a query that would exclude records where columns `Amount1, Amount2, Amount3, Amount4` have a value of 0 within the last 10 days.

Here is my attempt. Is there a better or correct way of doing this?

```
Select 
    count(*) 
from 
    table
Where 
    Amount1 Not In (select Amount1 from table where Amount1 = 0)
    And Amount2 Not In (select Amount2 from table where Amount2 = 0)
    And Amount3 Not In (select Amount3 from table where Amount3 = 0) 
    And Amount4 Not In (select Amount4 from table where Amount4 = 0)
    And Amount1 = ' & Item1 & '
    And Amount2 = ' & Item2 & '
    And Amount3 = ' & Item3 & '
    And Amount4 = ' & Item4 & '
    And DateColumn > = DateAdd(dd, -10, getdate())
```

Comment: So, did any of the answers help? Have you tried them? Any more questions? Please don't just disappear after we put time and effort into helping you!

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding, but you are overcomplicating it...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from table
WHERE Amount1 <> 0
AND Amount2 <> 0
AND Amount3 <> 0
AND Amount4 <> 0
AND DateColumn > = DateAdd("dd", -10, GetDate())
```

If you know your amount values can't be negative, use >0, it is more efficient than <>0.

What is the "item1" thing there for? You didn't mention that in your question.

Also, you need quotation marks for getdate's "dd".

Comment: A few mistakes I noticed and just my opinion. First one is `DateAdd("dd", -10, getdate())`. It should be `DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE())`. Secondly, using `Amount? <> 0` will include nullable fields of which he probably doesn't want if he's looking for something > 0.

Comment: @zaggler DATEADD works both ways. Using "dd" is an old habit of mine, mostly because I use Access frontends and that is the format MS Office programs recognizes. About `<>0` and `>0`, I did note that in my answer, but maybe OP wants negative values to be included too.

Answer (score 0):

Big performance issue the way you are currently approaching this. The nested `sub-selects` are killing the performance of your current query. Here is an alternative approach...

*Replace `@table` with your table name...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table
WHERE EXISTS(
                SELECT *
                FROM @table
                WHERE 
                    Amount1 > 0 AND
                    Amount2 > 0 AND
                    Amount3 > 0 AND
                    Amount4 > 0 AND
                    DateColumn >= DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE())
            )
```

On another note you are using `DateAdd` incorrectly. It should be: `DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE())`

Here's proof of the query from above...

[image]

Comment: Is the nested Select even necessary? I can't see what difference it makes (which may be my lack of insight).